# seeking melodic veda mantra recitations

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras, upanishads, vedic-chanting

I'm interested in locating Veda mantras with precise pronunciation of all alphabets (swar + akshar), akin to a melodious recitation. A notable example is the recitation of this Veda mantra from the śvetāśvataropaniṣad, presented in a melodious manner:

```
vedāhametaṁ puruṣaṁ mahāntamādityavarṇaṁ tamasaḥ parastāt
tameva viditvātimṛtyumeti nānyaḥ panthā vidyate'yanāya
```

as demonstrated in this [movie](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxD70ERqN4iUXnRqwyNw2C23krha3uKfnU?si=J0YzdNOT2KKCQzLe).

I reached out to the creator of the movie to inquire if there are more such mantra recitations available or if they could provide details about the audio creator, but haven't got any response yet.

I've also come across another recitation on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69iFb6FyOfE), although I'm uncertain about the accuracy of its pronunciation.